# Laravel delayed email triggering

Tags: php, laravel, email, scheduling

I would like to trigger a mail sent to user after registration (which is no problem), and then exactly a week after registration date, and then a month after registration date. So I was wondering how could I do that?

I think those may not go under Cron jobs since the task isn't really recurring, but rather triggered twice only.

Should I use `App->Console->Kernel.php` to set up a schedule with `when()` function or something similar? What would be the best approach?

Comment: there may be many registered users in table, so you can use cronjob on day basis. it's possible that someone has completed a week today and other one will complete a month today or tommoroww.

Answer (score 0):

This is opinion based, and thus not particularly well suited to the stackoverflow format, but here is how I'd do it:

Have flags on the user record for `1weekemail` and `1monthemail` which default to false.

Every night run two scheduled tasks which get a list of users who meet the time criterion but don't have the flag set.

Use that result set to send the emails, then set the appropriate flags to true.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `scheduler function` that checks for each registered user in your users table, it takes a user entry in which `last activity` or `registration time` is there, check for the time interval and send an email if the time interval condition satisfy and put this function on `schedule` like on daily basis or on hourly basis.